# I'm having trouble with \includegraphics I'm using MacTeX

Tags: pdf, graphics, import

Firstly and fore-mostly I am a *complete* new comer to the world of LaTeX and so please do bear with me. I will try to be as accurate as I can but if you need any more info please let me know.

All I want is to figure out how to import a graphic into LaTeX (MacTeX).

I am using the following in my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,draft]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Then in my document section I'm using

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width = 50mm]{Name.jpg}
\caption{Label}
\end{figure}
```

Once I compile the document, the area for the picture has been allocated but there is no image, I have tried .png and .pdf files also.

I know that this is a very simple question and I hope there is a simple solution but I cannot find anything on the net about this (which may mean I'm being dim).

Also I'm using Latexian but I have tried 4 different editors and it doesn't work in any.

Comment: In order to include a JPG image, you cannot compile using `latex`. You need to compile with a different compiler - `pdflatex`, for example.

Comment: Are you specifying the `draft` option with `\documentclass`?

Comment: You should always make small but *complete* examples like the one of Peter instead of sending code snippets. This will avoid that you left out important informations (like "are you using `draft` or not?"). You should also look in the log-file if there are errors or messages. If you don't understand the log: make it available on the net (remove confidential informations like your name if necessary but let everything else untouched).

Comment: Thank you everybody, It was in fact, that I was using the draft tag (this was automatically added to the preamble using a wizard). I apologise for not including the full code I was using. I was trying to be as specific as possible (due to the big ugly warning I got prior to posting the question) but unfortunately this back-fired. I do however know this for the future and will always try to include as much as I can. I suspect that as I become more acquainted with this very nice piece of software I will become more efficient at portraying my difficulties. Thanks again, your help is much apprecia

Comment: As suggested below I have now added the \documentclass that was causing the issue, when draft was changed to final, all worked

Comment: @Promethean_Sin This is not a forum, but a "Question and Answer" site. So you'd better comment on comments or answers, rather than adding a "non-answer" like this. However you will have to register, in order to do more things on the site. Welcome to TeX - StackExchange.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up egreg, So for future reference, should I only choose an answer supplied by another user rather than post my own?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the same directory where I have the file with the code below I have the file `EiffelTowerNight.jpg`. Typesetting the code below with `pfdlatex` results in the image being produced:

[image]

### Notes:

- If you add the `demo` option to the `graphicx` package as in
  `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`  then this will be displayed as

  [image]
- If you use the `draft` option to the class as in `\documentclass[draft]{article}`, then this will be displayed as:

  [image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = 50mm]{EiffelTowerNight.jpg}
    \caption{Label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe that if you leave the file extension off (.jpg, .pdf, etc), assuming you have the appropriate versions of your image file available, both the latex and pdflatex compilers will search for their 'preferred' image format and insert the image.  I have done this successfully but do not have the TeX code on hand.  Drop me a response if you'd like me to dig it up.

Comment: In view of the OP's comment, would you add the information about the `draft` option in `\documentclass`, that can be countermanded calling `graphics` with the `final` option?

Comment: let me know if you want anything else adding

Comment: @egreg: Added two failure modes: `draft` option for `\documentclass` and `demo` option for `graphicx`.